# Can someone please tell me the difference between Quansheng UV-5R, UV-5R (8) and UV-5R Plus?

Tags: uv-5r

I cannot find anywhere the difference between these 3 Quansheng radios...UV-5R, UV-5R(8) and UV-5R Plus. I have just purchased a UV-5R Plus...I know it has the AM air band, but I am not sure hyow any of the published firmware updates will effect it if I try to use then.